# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in window.open

Tags: javascript

We are getting :

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation for window open

It's pretty simple and it should work correctly.
when we do console it shows this

```js
var t = i(); 
// console.log(t);    output is https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=6666666666

(t += "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(a)),
    window.open(t, "_blank").focus(),
    I();
}
```

Any help will be great.

I am getting this error in

```js
window.open(twapp, "_blank").focus(),
```

[Here is the live site](https://www.mabrook.me/)

When you click on the chat in right bottom and tried to send msg this appears in console.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @Barmar edited and added live site

Comment: The error is happening in a minified library, making it nearly impossible to debug.